# Compiling from chapter

Tags: chapters, compiling

I'm new to LaTeX.
I created a new document with the following structure

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{appendix}

% ... %

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\input{./content/1-Introduction}
% ... %
\input{./content/7-Appendix}

\end{document}
```

When I compile it from the "main" file, everything works. But when I compile it from one of my chapter files, it says:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \chapter
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

A chapter looks like this:

```
\chapter{My Chapter}
% ... %
\section{...}
% ... %
```

Comment: I assume, you tried `pdflatex 1-Introduction`? That won't work, as a `\chapter` is a command only available in documentclass like `report` or `book` (or `scrreprt`) -- you are looking after the  `\includeonly` stuff

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I have a chapter named "1-Introduction", but the error also occurs with other chapters. Besides, my document is of class `scrreprt`.

Comment: what editor you have?

Comment: @touhami: Texmaker on Ubuntu.

Comment: @user1170330 In main file  go to options than to Define current... Now you can compile from others files

Comment: @user1170330: It's completely irrelevant which one of your chapter - related files you compile. You need a documentclass, see the answer by Andrew Cashner for example

Comment: @touhami: Thank you! That was fast and easy.

Comment: Hint: With `scrreprt` you most likely don't need package `appendix`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Every LaTeX document must start with `\documentclass`, include `\begin{document}` and end with `\end{document}`. Your chapter files don't have that so they can't compile by themselves.

But if you use `\include` instead of `\input` in the main file, then you can select parts to compile by using `\includeonly` in the preamble.

For example, use `\include{chapters/first} \include{chapters/second}` in the main document, and then add a line `\includeonly{chapters/first}` to the preamble and compile the main document.

Comment: You were quicker (good explanation +1);-)

Answer (score 2):

This shows the `\includeonly` approach, specifying only some of the files, although 'all' of them are given in the document as `\include{chapter1.tex}` etc.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{chapter1.tex}
\chapter{This is chapter one}
\blindtext

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{chapter2.tex}
\chapter{This is chapter two}
\blindtext

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{chapter3.tex}
\chapter{This is chapter three}
\blindtext

\end{filecontents}


\title{Some title}

% ... %

\includeonly{chapter1,chapter2}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents


\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}

%\input{./content/1-Introduction}
% ... %
%\input{./content/7-Appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good example! (+1) we might just paste the two together.

Answer (score 1):

You should write every chapter in a separate file (with `\chapter` issued right after `\begin{document}`), then load the package `docmute` in the main file: this package suppress `\end{document}` and all before `\begin{document}` included when you `\input` the chapter files.

Example:

ch01.tex:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
...text...
\end{document}
```

ch02.tex:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
...text...
\end{document}
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{docmute}
\begin{document}
\input{ch01}
\input{ch02}
\end{document}
```