# Trace errors when using \include

Tags: errors, include

I'm writting my thesis and decided to divide my main `.tex` file into different files containing the chapters using `\include`. However, when I compile my main file the error logs don't take me to the place of the error(the line number doesn't help either) when it occurs inside a chapter that has been included.
Is there a way to detect where are the errors in compilation when using `\include`?

PS. I'm using TexMaker

Comment: I guess you are working one one chapter at the time.Comment out the other `\include`s, the line number will be more helpful now. It decreases compile time as well.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Isn't `\includeonly{...}` the macro for 'commenting' out the stuff which is not needed?

Comment: Yes, I am already  using either `\includeonly{...}` or `\excludeonly{...}`. My question, though, is if there is a way to get the exact line of the error.

Comment: No, you cannot get the exact line. You can get the line that LaTeX notices the error.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, but i don't like it.

Comment: Examine the second answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230519/compiling-from-chapter/230528#230528. It is about using docmute.  When I build multichapter documents I often use this approach so that each chapter is separately compilable.  Then the error are correctly reported.

Comment: @R.Schumacher Thaks, that worked.

Comment: the line numbers should be just as accurate when you use `\include` as when you do not. What problem are you seeing?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I wanted to click on the error and go to the line of the included file where it was happening. The approach suggested by  
ChristianHupfer is working for me now.

Comment: @Ignacio any such behaviour is nothing to do with TeX and is a feature of your editor so the `PS` that you have at the end shouldn't be a footnote it is the main part of the question.